# Determine the regions in which each of the following series is convergent?

Tags: complex-analysis

$(i) \sum_{n=1}^ \infty \frac{z^n}{3^n + 1} $

$(ii) \sum_{n=1}^ \infty \frac{1}{(n + 1)z^n} $

Comment:I have attempted it and used the ratio test on both.

$(i)$ I have got to: limit at n tends of infinity of modulus of z*$(3^n+1))/(3^{n+1}+1)$ which gives $\mod(z/3)$ when n tends to infinity.So, the series converges for mod(z)less than 3. Is that correct?

$(ii)$ I have got to:limit at n tends of infinity of modulus of $((n+1)/((n+2)*z))$ which gives mod(1/z) when n tends to infinity. Not sure what to do next.

Comment: Is the first sequence supposed to be (z^n)/(3^n+1)?

Comment: no, it is (3^n)+1; And the second question is 1/((n+1)*(z^n))

Comment: Right, order of operations, we're saying the same thing.  In your question you have 3n+1.

Comment: no, i have edited the question and made it correct now.

Answer (score 1):

1) $lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}|\frac{z^n}{3^{n+1}+1}\frac{3^n+1}{z^n}| = lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}|z|\frac{1 +\frac{1}{3^n}}{3+\frac{1}{3^n}} = \frac{|z|}{3} \Rightarrow |z|<3$.

2) Let's make a substitution, let $\frac{1}{z} = a$

$lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}|\frac{a^{n+1}}{(n+1)+1}\frac{n+1}{a^n}| = lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}|a|\frac{n+1}{n+2} = |a| \Rightarrow |a| < 1$.  Then, $|a| = |\frac{1}{z}| < 1 \Leftrightarrow |z|>1$

Comment: thank you but (ii) has z^n in the denominator not numerator